# How to filter this nested list of Association

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, associations, query

For example, I have the following data

```
filenameData = {<|"parameter" -> <|"a" -> 1.`, "b" -> 10.`|>, 
   "filename" -> 
    "a_1_b_10"|>, <|"parameter" -> <|"a" -> 2.`, "b" -> 20.`|>, 
   "filename" -> 
    "a_2_b_20"|>, <|"parameter" -> <|"a" -> 3.`, "b" -> 30.`|>, 
   "filename" -> 
    "a_3_b_30"|>, <|"parameter" -> <|"a" -> 4.`, "b" -> 40.`|>, 
   "filename" -> "a_4_b_40"|>}
```

What I want to do is to filter parameters under the key "parameter".

For example, an `operation` select all "a" greater than 1, "b" greater than 20, and gives

```
operation[Select[(#a>1&&#b>20)&]@filenameData
(*{<|"parameter" -> <|"a" -> 3.`, "b" -> 30.`|>, 
  "filename" -> 
   "a_3_b_30"|>, <|"parameter" -> <|"a" -> 4.`, "b" -> 40.`|>, 
  "filename" -> "a_4_b_40"|>}*)
```

What is more, after filtering, get key "filename" or "parameter", something like

```
operation[Select[(#a>1&&#b>20)&,"filename"]@filenameData
(*{"a_3_b_30","a_4_b_40"}*)
operation[Select[(#a>1&&#b>20)&,"parameter"]@filenameData
(*{<|"a" -> 3.`, "b" -> 30.`|>,<|"a" -> 4.`, "b" -> 40.`|>}*)
```

I know the `operation` function I devised here should be `Query` function, and I don't need the parameter interface as exactly as I wrote above. But I just can not figure out how to do this case with `Query`(generally it is kind of filtering inner level, and selecting outer level).

Comment: I don't get what you want.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I just want a function `operation` which when apply on `filenameData` can produce results as  shown in my post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We must adjust the `Select` operator to account for the fact that the keys `"a"` and `"b"` are nested within the key `"parameter"`:

```
filter = Select[(#["parameter", "a"] > 1 && #["parameter", "b"] > 20) &];
```

We can then obtain the desired results using that filter:

```
Query[filter] @ filenameData

(*
    { <|"parameter" -> <|"a" -> 3., "b" -> 30.|>, "filename" -> "a_3_b_30"|>
    , <|"parameter" -> <|"a" -> 4., "b" -> 40.|>, "filename" -> "a_4_b_40"|>
    }
*)

Query[filter, "filename"] @ filenameData

(* {"a_3_b_30", "a_4_b_40"} *)

Query[filter, "parameter"] @ filenameData

(* {<|"a" -> 3., "b" -> 30.|>, <|"a" -> 4., "b" -> 40.|>} *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, WReach! It perfectly suits my need. It seems the key is that `assoc[key1, key2,...]` can traverse nested association.